# Изменение режима horizontal и vertical в Bxslider на Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, bxslider

Возможно ли поменять режим *bxslider* на маленьких размерах экрана с `horizontal` на `vertical` c помощью *jquery*?

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто отслеживать ширину контейнера (как собственно это делает css), и при достижении ширины для мобильных устройств (width < 800 px кажется ) тригернуть перерисовку . Метод `.on("resize",function(){})` [тык](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

```
slider.reloadSlider({
  mode: 'vertical',
  auto: true,
  pause: 1000,
  speed: 500
});
```

Но прежде чем так делать, советую завести объект с конфигурацией, чтобы именно его подставлять. Сам способ релоада собственно описан тут [тык](http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider-settings)